# Licence for DeepZoom and SeaDragaon AJAX?

Tags: silverlight, deepzoom, seadragon

wats the licence for  microsoft silverlight DeepZoom and SeaDragaon AJAX.. can i use the libraries in commercial applications.. or do i need to purchase any commercial licnence...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DeepZoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050(VS.95).aspx) is a feature of the Silverlight 3 product, and helped by the free [Deep Zoom Composer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=457b17b7-52bf-4bda-87a3-fa8a4673f8bf&displaylang=en) application.

The Silverlight platform is open for anyone to build applications on top of, so go at it and build something great!

For the second part, I'm a little unsure. As far as I can tell, the [SeaDragon AJAX](http://livelabs.com/seadragon-ajax/) is more of a "backup" plan, and being part of the Live Labs, might not be as well supported as a fully released product. However, there's nothing on the site to indicate that it cannot be used on a commercial site, other than the typical Live terms.

Comment: thanks Jeff for your reply... yes u r correct.. they explicitly dint mention anything abt licences.. thats wat am worried abt...

Comment: As far as I know, the only Live Labs app that requires commercial licensing of any kind is PhotoSynth.

Comment: i just go through the interesting link abt the same topic... http://getsatisfaction.com/livelabs/topics/seadragon_ajax_license

And microsoft guys responded and saying 

"Seadragon Ajax is currently "free as in beer", and there's virtually no chance that will ever change. But it's still an open issue whether it will be "free as in freedom".

If the worry about there being a price is what's blocking you, don't worry about that. Like Ian said, so far it's looking like we're settling on a license that will allow you to use it for commercial purposes."
so it allows commerical use??

Comment: Well, here's the good news: it works today, and you can always offer the Silverlight experience for free, regardless of any changes to the AJAX stuff.